# Printing one list with respect to the other in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists `B` and `X`. I want to create a new list `B1` which basically prints the values of `X` with indices according to `B`. But instead of writing it manually, I want to do it at one step. I present the expected output.

```
B=[[1,2],[3,4]]

X=[4.17551036e+02, 3.53856161e+02, 2.82754301e+02, 
            1.34119055e+02,6.34573886e+01, 2.08344718e+02, 1.00000000e-24]

B1=[[X[1],X[2]],[X[3],X[4]]]
```

The expected output is

```
[[3.53856161e+02,2.82754301e+02],[1.34119055e+02,6.34573886e+01]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
B1 = [[X[i] for i in indices] for indices in B]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[X[y] for y in sum(B, [])]
#[353.856161, 282.754301, 134.119055, 63.4573886]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in B:
    for j in i:
        j = X[j]
```

I haven't tested this but I believe it should work

Answer (score 0):

```py
B1 = [["{:.8e}".format(X[i]) for i in m] for m in B]
```

Output:

```
[[3.53856161e+02,2.82754301e+02],[1.34119055e+02,6.34573886e+01]]
```